# How can I solve this problem in vs code, ipython (tensorflow)?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network, ipython

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import check_util.checker as checker
from IPython.display import clear_output
from PIL import Image

import os
import time
import re
from glob import glob
import shutil
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow import keras

print('tensorflow version: {}'.format(tf.__version__))
print('GPU available: {}'.format(tf.test.is_gpu_available()))
```

When I run this, there is no error. But it shows as indefinitely in progress.

(Current 630..631..632...sec)

Comment: Please try to provide a minimal example, most of the lines in what you posted are irrelevant. If they should be irrelevant but are necessary to trigger the problem, say so. Say how you run the code, you speak of IPython and vs code, but how is that related.

Comment: @Matt 
First, thanks for answer. I would like to apologize if the content was lacking.
I tried to use a ipynb file by vs code.  This means using iPython. 

This is to import to use CNN using TensorFlow.
The above code worked fine before, but now when I run it, this error occurs.
So I was wondering if other people get the same error when I run this code. Also, I'm looking to see if anyone has ultimately resolved these errors.
(Ps. python ver.3.8.10 / tensorflow ver.2.3.0)